# Несколько исполняемых файлов для проекта VS2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

У меня есть решение (.sln) с 1 проектом. Можно ли как-то заставить VS2017 генерировать по этому проекту несколько исполняемых файлов (.exe), а именно: 1) win32 приложение; 2) win64 приложение; 3) приложение, использующее другой platform toolset (для старых версий Windows)?

Я знаю, как сделать это по отдельности, то есть каждый раз менять настройки и перезаписывать существующие файлы, но это, очевидно, неудобно.

Comment: Build -> Batch Build

Comment: @goldstar_labs я могу там настроить пункты 1) и 2), но как сделать 3) ?

Comment: @goldstar_labs кроме того, хоть и генерирует 1) и 2) одновременно, но на выходе похоже всё равно 1 исполняемый файл

Comment: В смысле 1? Настройте в солюшне разные пути для разных конфигураций и будет несколько файлов

Comment: @goldstar_labs ок, а как быть с другим toolset?

Comment: Я не помню есть ли там переменная для тулсета (типа $Platform), но чуть что можно сделать еще одну конфигурацию помимо дебаг/релиз

Comment: @goldstar_labs а если надо приложение с новым toolset и для debug, и для release, то делать 2 новых конфигурации: new_toolset_debug и new_toolset_release, соответственно копируя опции из существующих debug/release?

Comment: Вполне, Будет Debug, Debug_xp, другого простого способа не придумалось